# Why doesn't --type-set work in ack?

Tags: ack

In my .ackrc file I have this line

```
--type-set=vm=.vm
```

But when I run

```
ack-grep --vm blah
```

it searches all types of files.

Neither does this work:

```
ack-grep blah --type-set vm=.vm
ack-grep --type-set vm=.vm blah
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ack are you using?  1.x or 2.x?

Do you have any aliases on ack?  Are you invoking ack with `-a` behind the scenes somehow?

Comment: I'm running ack-grep version 1.92.  No aliases and no `-a`.

Comment: Are you sure about the no `-a`?  Try running `ack -f`, and then try `ack -f --noenv` and see if the results are different.

Comment: This may be better handled over on the ack-users mailing list.  Also, while you're at it, upgrade to ack 2.04.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice my `.ackrc` has a line `--all`. BTW, this has nothing to do with aliases since I don't have an alias `ack='ack-grep'`. Thanks!

Comment: What I have found in the past is that people have not the `ack=ack-grep` alias, but more often `ack='ack -a'` aiias.